# netcore 2.1: Cannot create logger with new LoggerFactory()

Tags: logging, .net-core

I'm upgrading a netcore 2.0 project to netcore2.1

I have a base test controller that creates a logger, like this:

```
public class WSTestController
{
    protected readonly ILogger _log;
    protected readonly HttpClient _client;
    protected readonly IServiceCollection _services;

    public WSTestController() {
        _log = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole().CreateLogger(this.GetType().Name);
        var testContext = new TestContext();
        _client = testContext.Client;
    }
```

This works fine with netcore 2.0, but in netcore 2.1 I get the following error:

```
controllers/WSTestController.cs(22,40): error CS1061: 
'LoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole' and no accessible extension method 'AddConsole' accepting a first argument of type 'LoggerFactory' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [[...]/src/mtss-ws.integrationtests/mtss-ws.integrationtests.csproj]
```

How Can I manually instantiate a console logger (that is without DI) in netvore 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

It should still work in netcore2.1, just look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLoggerFactoryExtensions.cs).

You can also do this manually by simply using AddProvider method:

```
loggerFactory.AddProvider(
    new ConsoleLoggerProvider(
        (text, logLevel) => logLevel >= LogLevel.Debug, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was related to my upgrading from netcore 2.0 to 2.1

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52073523/47633) I explain it, but basically I had to add a package reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in the test project, like stated in this [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#rules-for-projects-targeting-the-shared-runtime)