# Conflicts between different versions of Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: .net-core, json.net

I'm having a conflict between different versions of the assembly Newtonsoft.json between my Test project and the SUT.

I'm using .netcore 2.2

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106, 5): [MSB3277] Found
> conflicts between different versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that could
> not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build
> log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

---

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I think this might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072663/dotnet-core-2-1-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-when-referencin

Comment: did you ever resolve this?